# Java Naming Convention with Acronyms

Tags: java, naming-conventions

What is the correct name for the following Java class:
`DVDPlayer` or `DvdPlayer`?

Comment: I hate acronyms. `DigitalVersatileDiscPlayer` is the way forward.

Comment: +1 to Tom for the joke. I do find this question helpful if "correct" is reinterpreted as "standard" or "most typical". The accepted answer is great!

Comment: For me it makes sense to think of such acronyms as a single word and as such I follow the [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and use `DvdPlayer`.

Comment: [The style guide](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alundblad/styleguide/index-v6.html#toc-variables) has the following to say about it: *"Format an abbreviation as a word if the it is part of a longer class name."*, so `DvdPlayer` is the way to go. (And, for Tom, *"Use whole words and avoid using abbreviations unless the abbreviation is more widely used than the long form."*, and I think "DVD" is more widely used than "Digital Versatile Disc" :-)

Comment: You certainly meant "Discus", didn't you? :)

Comment: For the acryonym haters: some are good, e.g. foreign language ones. Example: CFI = Condor Flüge Individuell -> `isCfiBooking()` vs. `isCondorFlügeIndividuell()` in an international team with the source code language being English? Nah.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Since it looks like the answer is that there is no single standard for this in Java, I'd like to note that the .NET Framework Design Guidelines do specify this.

Now before slamming me for being off topic, please remember that the class naming guidelines for Java and the .NET Framework are quite similar, which makes the .NET guidelines useful as a persuasive reference.

### General Rules

Both guidelines recommend only using acronyms when the acronym is widely known and well understood. DVD or XML are excellent examples of this, as while you will recognize them immediately, it would take a bit longer to recognize the expanded version.

### Abbreviations

The .NET Framework Guidelines recommend not to use abbreviations (as opposed to acronyms), except that two common abbreviations `ID` and `OK` may be used in identifiers. When using an abbreviation, mixed case `Id` is always used except for the first word of a camelCase identifier (as opposed to a PascalCase identifier).

In Java this convention is followed only some of the time. [Take a look](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index-files/index-7.html) at how mixed the spellings `getID` and `getId` are in the JCL. (Scroll partway down that page). In the [Java 8 version](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index-files/index-7.html) though, `getId` is used more and more, which hints the PascalCase convention is preferred nowadays. It is best to just avoid abbreviations entirely when possible.

### Short Acronyms

The .NET Framework Guidelines say that two letter acronyms like `IO`, should have the same case for both letters. So for PascalCase identifiers (like a class name) you would get `DBRate`, while for a camelCase identifier (like a local variable) you might have `ioChannel`.

This definitely seems to be the prevailing convention in Java as well.

### Long Acronyms

The .NET Framework guidelines recommend that acronyms three letters or longer use mixed case for PascalCase and camelCase identifiers, except for the first word of a camelCase identifier. Thus for a class name you might have `XmlDocument`, while a local variable might be named `httpRequest`.

This convention is not always followed in Java. Four character acronyms do seem to usually use mixed case, but even the JCL is not consistent about three letter acronyms. Most of them seem to be all uppercase, like `URL`, `XML`, `SQL`, and `DOM`, but there are some exceptions like `Jar`.

### Conclusion

For Java:

For 4+ letter acronyms, use mixed case. The standard library does this, and it just makes good sense.

For 3 letter acronyms, you can use all uppercase like the JCL, or you can use mixed case like the .NET Framework does. Either way, be consistent.

For 2 letter acronyms, use all uppercase.

For 2 letter abbreviations, Java does not really have a standard, but I suggest using mixed case, unless consistency with other names would make all uppercase look better.

Comment: I like this, except that it's not consistent to have CAPS for 3- and 2-letter acronyms. (Maybe I'm to much of a purist, but see the accepted answer for practical reasons. Plus, there's the confusion factor.)

Comment: @JCoombs: Well, the inconsistancy for 2 letters is to something like `IpAddress` which looks terrible to many people. Personally when I need to write Java code, I go with mixed case for the 3 letter acronyms, leaving only the two letters as a special case.

Comment: What if your class name has multiple adjacent two-letter acronyms? Regardless of what you do, it'll look 'wrong' - USGFCharset, UsGfCharset, US_GFCharset...

Comment: Then what about XMLDBOK? I'd better see it as XmlDbOk and always use camelCase

Comment: @gaRex, The .Net guidelines say that that would be `XmlDbOk`. Db is considered an abbreviation rather than an acronym because database is one word. (I'll fix my answer). Abbreviations use PascalCase or camelcase. In java I would use probably use `XMLDbOk`, mainly for consistancy since XML is usually captialized in the core java frameworks.

Comment: > usually captialized in the core java frameworks

People traditionally thought, that Sun is around Earth. Orthodoxality is better in religion ))

Comment: Really good answer. But personally I don't like the .NET guidelines' idea of naming differently depending on length of acronyms and whether or not it is an abbreviation. Who actually cares about and checks the length of an acronym? Or if it is an abbreviation? I prefer a blanket rule for naming. The problem comes when using 3rd party libraries with different conventions from whatever rule you chose to go with.

Comment: based on answer I assume, `isValidDvd` will be preferred over `isValidDVD`

Comment: Seems few things are consistent in Java. For example, sentences in Javadocs don't always end in with periods or start with uppercase letters. Little things like that drives me nuts. You can at least follow well-known grammar rules.

Answer (score 114):

**There is no "correct" answer. Just a set of practices and conventions that better play with your other tools.**

Therefore I prefer `DvdPlayer`. It is more helpful as in Eclipse you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and pick classes by the first letter of each word.

[image]

Comment: Just "SIO" is sufficient to find that class.

Comment: This also works elsewhere in Eclipse - auto-complete for instance. Have a method/variable named 'myDvdCoverImage'? - just type mDCI Ctrl+Space

Comment: there is also some shortcuts already set, like sysout Ctrl+Space, gives you System.out.println. same goes for (try) and (for)

Comment: That works in IntelliJ too with Ctrl+N

Comment: Try "sioobe" in IntelliJ :-)

Answer (score 60):

I've seen both of them used in the wild, and Sun seems to go for the `DVDPlayer` style. I prefer `DvdPlayer`, though, because that way it is clear where the word boundaries are even if there are multiple consecutive acronyms, as in `HTTPURLConnection`.

Comment: It's also faster to type this way.

Comment: I think "DVDPlayer" makes the word boundaries more clear. "Dvd" is not a word, whereas "DVD" is an acronym for the words "Digital Versatile Disc". So the actual word boundaries in "DVD Player" are at "D", "V", "D", and "P".

Comment: @GregBrown: A DVD is a disc with a hole, nobody except you knows its full name, neither cares about it. And it is far more practical to use DvdPlayer.

Comment: @IgorRodriguez: Just because you like "DvdPlayer" better does not make it any more practical than "DVDPlayer". The point is that, when speaking, acronyms are read letter by letter, not pronounced like an actual word. In my opinion, class and method names should mirror this convention.

Comment: @GregBrown: In fact it is more practical at least in Eclipse, where the camel-case recognition is a pain with acronyms: i.e. with DvdPlayer you can type "DP" and press Ctrl+1 to get the choice to select DvdPlayer, but if you had DVDPlayer you would have to type "DVDP". And is even more annoying if it is longer. I wouldn't like to have an UNESCOConnector in my code. Anyway it is a matter of choice.

Comment: Another good example is HTTPSID - did I mean HTTP SID or HTTPS ID...
Therefore it should be written HttpSid or HttpsId respectively to better explain the meaning.

Comment: What about acronym PET vs word Pet? If you use camelcase for acronyms e.g. PetService, it's not clear whether you mean PET or Pet.

Comment: @onepiece - you'll run into this sort of thing anyways if you create an all-caps constant. is PET_ID referring to PET or pet? A reader should hopefully be able to figure it out based on context.

Answer (score 48):

I like to define individual instances of classes in the following fashion:

```
Catalogue catalogue;
Person person;
```

Therefore, if I used `DVDPlayer`, what would I call an instance of that? `dVDPlayer`? Hence I'd choose the `DvdPlayer` class name, so you can name the instances like `dvdPlayer`.

Comment: What's wrong with `DVDPlayer dvdPlayer;`?

Comment: @DerFlatulator What's not wrong with it? No matter how you came to `dvdPlayer`, when you go back, you'll get `DvdPlayer`.

Comment: @DerFlatulator: it's a question of automation when converting from UpperCamelCase to lowerCamelCase: I had the problem when automating Hibernate mapping to a snake_case: `DvdPlayer -> dvd_player` but `DVDPlayer -> d_v_d_player`. There is no way to automate DVDPlayer to dvd_player.

Comment: @pdem `/^([A-Z]+)[A-Z]\w+$/` and `$1` to lower case?

Comment: @DerFlatulator: okay,thanks for the reply, it worked in this case. But I'm still convinced with the "DvdPlayer" notation: what about DVDRPGPlayer?, it should be converted to dvdRpgPlayer, not dvdrpgPlayer.

Comment: Also consider your getters and setters:  `getDvdPlayer()` works better than `getDVDPlayer()`, for example, when used with JSP EL (e.g., `foo.dvdPlayer`).  And if you're naming your getters with lowercase in the acronyms, it's best to keep your class names the same for consistency and predictability.

Answer (score 41):

Some examples from the JavaSE classes, apache commons and spring:

- `HttpURLConnection`
- `HTTPAddress`
- `UrlPathHelper`
- `AopProxy`
- `ISBNValidator`

So - it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Agreed. Just be consistent in your code base.

Comment: I wouldn't say it doesn't matter, although this one is not exactly a big deal. Some of use find generally-preferred standards very helpful, even if not everyone else is consistent about following them.

Answer (score 30):

[Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA237) seems to prefer DvdPlayer.

Answer (score 15):

As others have indicated, its a style thing that differs across projects. Google projects such as Guava and GWT prefer the `DvdPlayer` style.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case

Comment: A more general Google convention link for `DvdPlayer` style: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case

Comment: The link in the answer has moved to http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html#codestyle

The link @StanKurdziel mentions has moved to https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case

Answer (score 8):

From [sun java docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html):

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

Comment: That doesnt really say anything about whether it should be upper or camel case.

Comment: @DD. I think to me, "much more widely used" points to use all-caps for relevant acronyms (HTTP, GET, etc) than for some random business-specific word like DVD, MRI, MAGA, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`DVDPlayer` is the standard, but `DvdPlayer` is not uncommon.

You more often than not see `getId`. That's probably due to thinking ID is a shortening of "Identity". It is actually the initials of Identity Document.

`HttpURLConnection` is often given as an example of mixed convention. However, "http" used as protocol name in a URL should be lower case (although upper case is often accepted).

Comment: I don't think this is really a standard, but it is probably the most common.

Comment: It's in the Sun Java Coding Standard, IIRC. Although not in the JLS.

Comment: HyperTextTransferProtocolUniformResourceLocatorConnection

Comment: I'm pretty sure most people use ID as an abbreviation of Identifier...i.e. in a database the table ID is referring to the table identifier to the identity document.

Comment: DVDPlayer is definitely not the standard; even the JDK is wildly inconsistent in their approach to this.

Comment: The Java library is inconsistent in a number of ways (my favourite example is `javax.xml.parsers` vs `javax.xml.transform`). However, it is quite consistent with initials using caps, as in `DOMURIReference`. I guess most of the counterexamples come through JSRs where there spec lead has gone off and done something odd.

Comment: So "getId" means "get identity" and getID means "get identity document"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct", only preferences here.

Sun is consistent in the way they name classes containing "URL" and "HTML", but I see HTTP using both all caps and camel case in the javadocs.

Personally, I'd prefer DvdPlayer.

Comment: I believe the HTTP protocol name in URLs should be written in lower case (although it may be accepted in upper case by browsers).