# naming conventions for DynamoDB?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Background: I'm creating kind of simplified pseudo-ORM for use in Django. Classes obviously use CamelCase convention, while Django app is underscored lowercase. Which leaves me with a few options:

- Django ORM style: `app_name_someclass`
- proper underscore style: `app_name_some_class`
- as-is: `app_name.SomeClass`
- possibly some other using different separators etc.

**Are there any well established naming conventions for DynamoDB**? 
So far, from what I've seen in examples, it seems that it's free-for-all.

Comment: kinda late now but anyone looking at this question can look at the official AWS documentation with example Tables and Data https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleTables.html

Comment: @chris so PascalCase

Answer (score 20):

Following the examples in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleTables.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html) would lead to the following conventions:

1. Table names in Pascal Case (Upper Camel Case), e.g. `MyTable`.
2. Attribute names also in Pascal Case, e.g. `Id`, `ProductCategory` etc.

*Some of the examples are a bit inconsistent when it comes to acronym capitalization - with `ISBN` and `Id` in the first link and both `CustomerID` and `CustomerId` in the second link. Either style could be argued but I'd personally lean towards only capitalizing the first letter in an acronym. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase) for more debate on this subject.*

Comment: Sorry for the nitpick, but the correct case naming is `PascalCase`.

Comment: Don't mind the nitpick but Upper Camel Case is an equivalent term. Anyway have now edited to refer to Pascal Case.

Comment: You're definitely right, sorry about it, wasn't even a nitpick, just a straight ignorance on my part!

Answer (score 8):

It's free for all. I name tables as `"users"`, `"secret-files"`, `"seen-blog-posts"`, and their attributes as `"user.name"`, `"date.recent.iso"`, etc.