# Recommendation on using abbreviations in CamelCase from Code Complete

Tags: coding-style, camelcasing, abbreviation, acronym, code-complete

In the latest code review I was asked, why did I change the method name from `GetHDRFrame` to `GetHdrFrame`, while [HDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging) is an abbreviation. I'm pretty sure there was such recommendation in Code Complete: when using abbreviations in CamelCase names, treat them as regular words. But I cannot find the place where it is written. Could somebody give me an exact phrase in Code Complete, where it is stated?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase) with the useful links to MS rules, but I'm looking for Code Complete quote.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to determine, there is no such advice in Code Complete. But [it](http://books.google.com/books?id=I-83BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA866&ots=4EQ-vHkz8v&dq=%22Code%20Complete%22%20page%20271&pg=PA274#v=snippet&q=%22People%20have%20managed%20to%20have%22&f=false) does say:

> People have managed to have zealous, blistering debates over fine
>   points such as whether the first character in a name should be
>   capitalized (*TotalPoints* vs. *totalPoints*), but as long as you and
>   your team are consistent, it won't make much difference.

And that may help you avoid such nitpicking in future code reviews. ;-)

Comment: The link should let you search through the text -- please post if you find the quote you were thinking of!