# Acronyms in camelCase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions

CamelCase is a convention and not a specification, so when there is a doubt it is common sense to stick to the language specification or implementation's naming convention.

The doubt I came across several times is acronyms. As [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186277/should-the-variable-be-named-id-or-id) and [this answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase) it seems that Microsoft and .NET usually goes for camelCase for acronyms as in **XmlDocument** apart for 2 letters acronyms as in **System.IO** whereas Java prefers to always go for capitalized acronyms like **SAXParser**. Id, I think, is a different thing because it is an abbreviation of identifier rather than an acronym.

That being said, I would like to apply one of those conventions to JavaScript, so I started thinking that it would go towards the Java standard, but I found some weird things like **window.XMLHttpRequest** which mixes everything up.

Why is XML capitalized while HTTP is camelCased ? What is the common convention for JavaScript ?

Comment: I don't think that there's a common language convention. E.g. `XMLHTTPBindingCodec` goes for all caps....

Comment: @msparer yes, well, this is Java and they always go for all caps so ti seems ok. JavaScript seems to be a lot more confusing