# Uppercase or lowercase confusion at the end of the acronyms in Coding Convention

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions, camelcasing, acronym

For example; I have a function named  that;

```
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPM_ ( int channel );
```

I want to divide it into left and right. But short of ***Revolutions Per Minute*** at the end, restricts me from that kind of renaming;

```
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPML_ (void);
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPMR_ (void);
```

It irritates, other Posible renames;

```
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPM_L_ (void);
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPMl_  (void);
int ReadEncoderSpeedRPMl_  (void);
int ReadEncoderSpeedRpmL_  (void); // My Favourite but I think I'm losing Acronym...
int ReadEncoderSpeedrpmL_  (void);
```

Which one (or another one) is most recommended, suggested, and Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526526/5272038) post, it looks like `int ReadEncoderSpeedRpmL_  (void);` seems like the right option.

Comment: Do you think this question is duplicate or it is a little bit different? I think may be duplicate but I couldn't find that link before. Oh God, This site has an every answer...

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a naming like that

```
int ReadEncoderSpeedRpmLeft (void);
int ReadEncoderSpeedRpmRight (void);
```

In my opinion it is more readable if you **don't** use an abbreviation for Left and Right.