# What are the different camel casings of acronyms called?

Tags: naming-conventions, uppercase

As discussed in [acronyms in CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase), there are two opposing schools of camel casing – about whether acronyms should be uppercased or not – and there are also some styles inbetween that prescribe a bit of both. From that discussion, we may tentatively name them:

1. UnescoCase
2. XMLHTTPRequestCase
3. a bit of both:

   - length based rules:

     - MicrosoftIOCase (two letter rule)

Are there any existing names for this distinction? XMLHTTPRequestCase is a bit of a mouthful.