# What are the camel case rules for words like "iPhone", 'jQuery", "eBay", etc?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I need to write a method called "set jQuery data" and I'm stuck on the formatting.

- `setJQueryData`? (I feel this wins on readability but I'm uncertain it's correct.)
- `setJqueryData`?
- `setjQueryData`?

Comment: AFAIK it's `setJqueryData` even for names and abbreviations. The reason is automatic tooling like Angular cli generator. A name like `setJqueryData` would be converted to `set-jquery-data`. `setJQueryData` would be converted to `set-j-query-data`. `setjQueryData` would be converted to `setj-query-data`.

Comment: You can see [Acronyms in CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase) for a lot of discussion but it too was closed for being opinion based.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jabaa, thank you, that was a plenty good reason for me to settle for `setJqueryData`.

Answer (score 1):

Camel Case should never have two capital letters in a row and is generally the first letter of each word.  jQuery is one word.  Therefore, `setJqueryData`

On a sidenote, ebay is now all lowercased and is no longer eBay