# How to persist data from the entity class and combined with data transfer object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, thymeleaf

I'm working on an authentication feature and have run into an issue with persisting the data from the entity class.   I'm able to access the password_hash and the username from the data transfer object but am not able to see the email, firstName, lastName, or phoneNumber from the User class in the database. The photo below is an example of what happens when I register a new user. You can see that there are 4 columns without data. [image]

When I'm adding a `newUser` I use a processRegistrationForm method that looks like this...

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid RegisterFormDTO registerFormDTO,
                                          Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request,
                                          Model model) {

        // a few conditionals that I removed for brevity

        User newUser = new User(registerFormDTO.getUsername(), registerFormDTO.getPassword(), registerFormDTO.getFirstName(), registerFormDTO.getLastName(), registerFormDTO.getEmail(), registerFormDTO.getPhoneNumber());
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        setUserInSession(request.getSession(), newUser);

        return "redirect:";
    }
```

the registerFromDTO

```
public class RegisterFormDTO extends LoginFormDTO{

    private String verifyPassword;


    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private String phoneNumber;
//getters and setters.
```

the LoginFormDTO

```
public class LoginFormDTO {

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Invalid username. Must be between 3 and 30 characters.")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Invalid password. Must be between 5 and 30 characters.")
    private String password;
//getters and setters
```

the User class..

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String pwHash;

    //@Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    //@Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    //@Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    //@Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    public User() {}

    private static final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber){
        this.username =username;
        this.pwHash = encoder.encode(password);
        this.firstName =firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public boolean isMatchingPassword(String password) {
        return encoder.matches(password, pwHash);
    }
//getters and setters
```

Last but not least here is my register form view

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username
            <input class="form-control" th:field="${registerFormDTO.username}" />
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${registerFormDTO.username}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password
            <input class="form-control" th:field="${registerFormDTO.password}" type="password" />
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${registerFormDTO.password}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Verify Password
            <input class="form-control" th:field="${registerFormDTO.verifyPassword}" type="password" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name
            <input class="form-control" th:field="${registerFormDTO.firstName}" type="firstName" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name
            <input class="form-control" th:field="${registerFormDTO.lastName}" type="lastName" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does `RegisterFormDTO` in `processRegistrationForm` method contains valid values from form view?

Comment: @mslowiak I have two fields that I’m validating and have not gotten any errors.  Do I need to add additional validation annotations to the other fields?

Comment: I am just asking if any value is present in `RegisterFromDTO` instance after calling that method. Especially if `registerFormDTO.getUsername()` got some value or it is a null itself

Comment: @mslowiak There were three values that were present in RegisterFormDTO:  `verifyPassword`, `username` and `password`.

Comment: So it looks like you render register form with `LoginFormDTO` as a model and not `RegisterFromDTO `...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form needed to include a few things to persist the data collected in `registerFormDTO`.  The first was: 
1.  In the form tag, add the `th:action="@{/register}"`and `th:object="registerFormDTO"`
2.  In the input tags add `type="text"` to each input field and change where `type="password"`, `type="firstName"` etc... to `id="password"` , and `id="firstName"` etc..

Doing these things allow Thymeleaf to wire up and persist the data that is collected.

Here is the full code.

```
<form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${registerFormDTO}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.username}" id="username" />
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${registerFormDTO.username}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.password}" id="password" />
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${registerFormDTO.password}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Verify Password
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.verifyPassword}" id="password" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.firstName}" id="firstName" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.lastName}" id="lastName" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.email}" id="email" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${registerFormDTO.phoneNumber}" id="phoneNumber" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapStruct to map from DTO to the model.

For example:

```java
    @Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="employeeId", source="entity.id"),
      @Mapping(target="employeeName", source="entity.name")
    })
    EmployeeDTO employeeToEmployeeDTO(Employee entity);
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="id", source="dto.employeeId"),
      @Mapping(target="name", source="dto.employeeName")
    })
    Employee employeeDTOtoEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);
}
```

"[Quick Guide to MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)" has more information.

Comment: Please don't say "...more here." Use something more descriptive. The following pages help explain: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)",
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
and "[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"