# is it possible to print only one statement in this nested if code?-Java

Tags: java, nested-if

Our professor asked us to create a code that prints what grade you should be getting for a particular score, in a nested if code in Java

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nestedif {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tscore = sc.nextInt();

        if (tscore >=60){
            System.out.println("D");
            if (tscore >=70){
                System.out.println("C");
                if (tscore >=80){
                    System.out.println("B");
                    if (tscore >=90){
                        System.out.println("A");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("tae");
        }
    }
}
```

it prints the grade but it also includes the first if's statement
ex
input: 90
output: A
B
C
D

Comment: So, do it as a series of `if`/`else if` statements.  `if( tscore >= 90 )` ... `else if( tscore >= 80 )`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code prints multiple grades at the same time because when you enter `90`, the condition is true for multiple `if` conditions. Not only you need to use `else if`, but also you need to specify the ranges for the grades as in `tscore >= 60 && tscore < 70`. So, your code should look like below;

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tscore = sc.nextInt();

    if (tscore >= 60 && tscore < 70) {
        System.out.println("D");
    } else if (tscore >= 70 && tscore < 80) {
        System.out.println("C");
    } else if (tscore >= 80 && tscore < 90) {
        System.out.println("B");
    } else if (tscore >= 90) {
        System.out.println("A");
    } else {
        System.out.println("tae");
    }
}
```

I would probably execute my code in debug mode to see the behaviour.

Comment: @user16320675 if you do not test for `>= 70`, then `40` will return as `C`. If you do not test `< 70`, then 90 will return as `D`. So, it is needed.

Comment: @user16320675 you are right. But, this is an answer to OP's question (working version of OP's code), not the best solution. I would test the higher score `>= 90` first to avoid double-condition checks in each statement.

Answer (score 0):

DO it using `if/ else if`. Like `if(tscore >= 90)`, `else if(tscore>=80)` continue...

Answer (score 0):

The the ifs are inside each other, u just need separet with if-else-if

```
if(tscore >= 90){
  //do something
}else if(tscore >=80){
   //do another thing
 }else{
  //tae
 }
```

Class names in Java are capitalize [more about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649943/naming-convention-for-class-in-java-all-caps)

Comment: I think you have to check the highest value first or the `if else` doesn't work properly for this case.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, I passed quickly and did not pay attention